# to clear the debris

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, clauses

a. A surgeon is needed to operate on Tom.

b. A surgeon is needed for operating on Tom.

==================

c. Shovels are needed to clear the debris.

d. Shovels are needed for clearing the debris.

Which of the above sentences are grammatically correct?

We have two different cases. In the first case, the surgeon is going to do the operation. In the second, the shovels are going to be used to clear the debris by people.

I think (a) is fine. I have doubts about (b). It seems to me that (c) and (d) both work, but I am not sure. I prefer (c).

Comment: They all seem fine to me. The choice probably depends upon context and how it reads in conjunction with the rest of the text.

Comment: Both are syntactically fine, but the infinitive versions *(**to operate, to clear**)* are idiomatically more natural in both cases. This is particularly the case for the first *(**operating**)* context - imho the reason for that is "operating on Tom" is a very long way from being a "familiar, recognisable action", and the *[needed] **for** [activity or purpose]* usage works best with known generic "activity" complements that many people both do and recognize, such as ***clearing** [the] **debris***.